# default behavior of less on .iso files

Tags: 14.04, iso, less

I use ubuntu 14.04 and have the following problem.  Searching this website doesn't turn up anything and neither does google.

I work with some data files that have a suffix .iso.  These are simple ascii data files, not [ISO images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image).  However, when I try to 'less' one of these files in the terminal, I get the error message:

```
CD-ROM is NOT in ISO 9660 format
```

In other words, it thinks they are ISO images because of the suffix.  The 'more' utility treats them as regular text files but does not have as many convenient options as 'less'.

Can I change the default behavior for this file suffix?  And, if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what is happening is that the file handling is being intercepted by the default `lessfile` *input preprocessor*. Although I don't have any experience with it,  according to `man lessfile` it is possible to override the default behaviour as follows:

```
USER DEFINED FILTERS
       It  is  possible to extend and overwrite the default lesspipe and less‐
       file input processor if you have specialized  requirements.  Create  an
       executable  program with the name .lessfilter and put it into your home
       directory. This can be a shell script or a binary program.
.
.
.
```

However, if your files are plain ASCII text, it may be sufficient for your needs to simply disable the preprocessor altogether - either by setting an empty `LESSOPEN` environment variable

```
LESSOPEN= less yourfile.iso
```

or using the `-L` command line option

```
less -L yourfile.iso
```

From `man less`:

```
   -L or --no-lessopen
          Ignore the LESSOPEN environment variable  (see  the  INPUT  PRE‐
          PROCESSOR  section  below).   This option can be set from within
          less, but it will apply only to files opened  subsequently,  not
          to the file which is currently open.
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this answer due to previous answer look alike environmental trick which slightly "too odd" or redundantly inefficient.

Most likely format for **simple & usual ASCII** binary is `.txt`:
[American Standard Code for Information Interchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file#ASCII)

You have all chances to save your ASCII to `.txt`, and to save your `.txt` inside standard `.iso`, and you have the same way you can run these files with **STANDART** environment.

Because `.iso` file format is about disk images.